# Add concatenated property to ado.net edmx

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I know this must be real simple but after hours of searching online I can't find anything that tells me how to add a concatenated property to the ado.net data entity model designer.
I have a class library project that holds the edmx classes, database first, and I tried to add a partial class with the same namespace and the following...

```
   public string ValueKey
   {
       get
       {
           return string.Concat(Value, "-", Key);
       }
   }
```

but It doesn't find the values even though the correct table is referenced.

So basically I need to concatenate two fields from the options table using the ado.net data entity model diagram.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: `"It doesn't find the values even though the correct table is referenced"` you mean `Value` and `Key` properties?

Answer (score 0):

Sheri, make sure that the signature of your partial class is correct (have you specified `partial` keyword?), and double check the location of your code so that it is the exact same namespace

```
public partial class Options
{
   public string ValueKey
   {
       get
       {
           return string.Format("{0}-{1}", Value, Key);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did specify partial. I also checked the namespace.  I am not sure but from what I understand that since I'm using the edmx file instead of creating my own classes, I have to use the designer.

Comment: I also used the edmx, and have custom partial classes